# Google gapi/platform.js library deprecated: how to use gapi.client.classroom?

Tags: javascript, api, google-classroom, google-identity

Google is deprecating its gapi/platform.js client from end of March 2023.
We are using the gapi client to interact with the Google Classroom API, first to set the required scopes (including classroom.coursework.me):

```
googleSignInStudentAuth: function() {
    var vm = this;
    var options = new gapi.auth2.SigninOptionsBuilder();
    options.setPrompt('select_account');
    options.setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email').setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile').setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me');
    var instance = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    instance.signIn(options).then(function(googleUser) {
      app.onSignIn(googleUser);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
  },
```

And then to turn in a submission with:

```
var response =
          await gapi.client.classroom.courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.turnIn(
            params
          );
```

I cannot find anything in the documentation for the new identity services API (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) about how to request specific SCOPES including classroom.coursework.me.

In addition, it seems that the Google Classroom API documentation is still using gapi in its examples (https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/js)

If anyone has experience transitioning over to the new Identity Services API specifically for Google Classroom, I would appreciate any help or advice you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Though the documentation is confusing, I don't believe the gapi/platform.js library itself is being deprecated, but rather, only the `auth2` module within that library.

From the [announcement](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/03/gis-jsweb-authz-migration.html):

> Web applications using gapi.client from the Google API Client Library implicitly load and use the Platform Library’s soon to be deprecated gapi.auth2 module when working with access tokens to call Google APIs. Updates to your web app to explicitly include the new Identity Services library, manage access token requests, and replace auth2 module references with newer equivalent methods are necessary.

This is not obvious, but in any case, you can [set a cookie to test if your current usage depends on the deprecated module](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration#identifying_affected_code_and_testing) (and you should be seeing console warnings as well).

The documentation you linked is using the new GSI library (which replaces the `auth2` module behavior) alongside the `gapi` client:

```
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
<script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
```

So it should still serve as a valid reference, provided you are testing with `auth2` disabled as described above.